# How can I check if exists file with name according to "template" in the directory?

Tags: bash, variable-expansion

Given variable with name `template` , for example: `template=*.txt`.
How can I check if files with name like this template exist in the current directory?

For example, according to the value of the `template` above, I want to know if there is files with the suffix `.txt` in the current directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `find`:

```
: > found.txt  # Ensure the file is empty
find . -prune -exec find -name "$template" \; > found.txt
if [ -s found.txt ]; then
  echo "No matching files"
else
  echo "Matching files found"
fi
```

Strictly speaking, you can't assume that `found.txt` contains exactly one file name per line; a filename with an embedded newline will look the same as two separate files. But this does guarantee that an empty file means no matching files.

If you want an accurate list of matching file names, you need to disable field splitting while keeping pathname expansion.

```
[[ -v IFS ]] && OLD_IFS=$IFS
IFS=
shopt -s nullglob
files=( $template )
[[ -v OLD_IFS ]] && IFS=$OLD_IFS
printf "Found: %s\n" "${files[@]}"
```

This requires several `bash` extensions (the `nullglob` option, arrays, and the `-v` operator for convenience of restoring `IFS`). Each element of the array is exactly one match.

Comment: And apart of `find` you meet more way to solve it? I ask it because that I want to know how can I really take template from the `template` and to use it.

Comment: Namely, how can I check given argument from the user if it's from the template of `template` ? (namely, if  `$1 == ${template}` , but sure, it's not working like that).

Comment: This recurses into subdirectories, I understand the question that it should check only files in the current directory.

Comment: @BenjaminW. Fixed, I think.

Comment: @AskMath That's a different question. If you just want to match a string with a pattern, use `if [[ $1 == $template ]]; then ...; fi`.

Comment: ...and the `IFS` isn't actually changed in the second one ;)

Comment: but not really to the value of `${template} `, But rather, to relate to what it represents

Comment: @BenjaminW. Details, details ;)

Comment: And I'll shut up after this, but I think it should be `-maxdepth 1` instead of `-prune`, `-prune` suppresses all results for me.

Comment: @chepner Ok, in fact I think that it's a different question, so I opened other question about that.

Comment: @BenjaminW. Hm, that's a bummer; I wanted to stick to POSIX options for the `find` solution. I mistakenly thought `-prune` and `-maxdepth 1` were equivalent.

Comment: One could use `find ./* -prune -name ...`, I guess, but that `./*` adds back the problem of blowing up the command line that you often use `find` to avoid. Is there a better workaround to avoid `-maxdepth 1`?

Comment: Maybe this? https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/24557/how-do-i-stop-a-find-from-descending-into-found-directories

Comment: `find . -prune -exec find -name "$template" \;` works for me and seems to be POSIX-only.

Answer (score 4):

I would do it like this with just built-ins:

```
templcheck () {
    for f in * .*; do
        [[ -f $f ]] && [[ $f = $1 ]] && return 0
    done
    return 1
}
```

This takes the template as an argument (must be quoted to prevent premature expansion) and returns success if there was a match in the current directory. This should work for any filenames, including those with spaces and newlines.

Usage would look like this:

```
$ ls
 file1.txt  'has space1.txt'   script.bash
$ templcheck '*.txt' && echo yes
yes
$ templcheck '*.md' && echo yes || echo no
no
```

To use with the template contained in a variable, that expansion has to be quoted as well:

```
templcheck "$template"
```

Comment: What is `for f in * .*; do` say?

Comment: Namely, what is the meaning of `.*` in this context?

Comment: @AskMath It iterates over all files in the directory. Because `*` skips hidden files (starting with `.`), I added `.*` explicitly so also hidden files are iterated over. Otherwise, a pattern like `.abc*` would never match.

Comment: There's also the `dotgob` option to let `*` match the same files as `.*`.

Comment: @BenjaminW. Ok , and you know how can I write for example `rm ${template}` for removes all the files from this template? While I try to do only `rm "${template}"` , it's remove only the first file from this template. Namely, while I doing `rm *.ord` so it's removes all the files with prefix of `.ord`, but while I doing `rm "${template}"` It's not happens

Comment: @AskMath It would work with `rm $template` (unquoted) if there are no blanks in the template. If there might be blanks, you could adapt my function to do `rm "$f"` instead of `return 0`. `find` with `-exec rm {}` or `-delete` (if you have GNU `find`) might be more convenient.

Comment: @AskMath You must not quote `$template` on the right-hand side of `[[ ]]`.

Comment: @AskMath Your template is `.ord`, but it should be `*.ord`.